# What's wrong with this usage of select()?

Tags: python

Basically I wanted to write a function that will merge stdout and stderr of `subprocess.Popen` (or in general case of any input file descriptors) into one generator that gives me `(file_descriptor, line)`  tuples.

My first attempt looked like this:
    from select import select
    import subprocess

```
def _merge_proc_output( process ):
    inputs = (process.stdout, process.stderr)
    while process.poll() is None:
        for f in select(inputs , (), () )[0]:
            line = f.readline()
            if len(line): yield f, line
```

It seemed to work most of the time. For i.e. 10 runs only one gets corrupted (point is that it is *random*). Occasionally it misses some lines and I *think* it is always lines at the end. Unfortunately it is not something that I was able to reproduce consistently, so it is very hard to debug.

Can anyone see what is the issue with above code that would cause it to drop lines from the end of one of streams?

Currently I use more resource hungry and verbose code, but more portable:

```
import subprocess
import threading
from Queue import Queue

def _merge_proc_output( process ):
    q = Queue()
    def push(fd):
        for l in fd:
            q.put((fd, l))
        q.put(None)

    pipes   = (process.stdout, process.stderr)
    threads = [ threading.Thread( target = push, args = (fd,) ) for fd in pipes ]

    [ t.start() for t in threads ]

    for t in threads:
        while True:
            w = q.get()
            if w is None:
                break
            yield w

    [ t.join() for t in threads ]
```

And this seems to work fine (or at least I haven't noticed issues yet). Still I would like to know what is wrong with my original code.

P.S. if you see issues with second solution please do comment on that also.

**edit:**
Hm, possibly I have an idea why it happens. Assuming my observation about only last lines missing it might be that `process.poll()` returns something, but there is still stuff in output buffers for those streams.
I have modified my original function by adding loop that tries to read everything from output streams:

```
def _merge_proc_output( process ):
    inputs = (process.stdout, process.stderr)
    while process.poll() is None:
        for f in select(inputs , (), () )[0]:
            line = f.readline()
            if len(line): yield f, line
    for i in inputs:
        for l in i:
            yield i,l
```

I have to have a bit of play to check if this fixes my issues.

Comment: That [select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html). I am not aware of any other, so I thought it was obvious which one I meant. Amended question to include that information.

Comment: @user2357112 please see this: http://linux.die.net/man/2/select

Comment: @elmo: list comprehensions are no substitute to normal for-loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the subprocess terminates, you immediately stop reading its output. That means that if you weren't done reading what was already produced, you lose the lines at the end.

Comment: ...and it looks like you came up with this or something very similar about half a minute ago.

Comment: Yeah, will play around to confirm it actually solves my issue (sadly, due to its randomness I will never be 100% sure). Will accept this answer if it does.